# Building static curl library

Tags: curl, visual-studio-2022, nmake

I'm trying to build static curl library using VS Developer Command Prompt.
But when I run `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static` I get `winerror.h: No such file or directory`.
I have Windows SDK installed and all necessary files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared`, but for some reason it cannot be found. How do I specify the path to them for makefile or what else should I do in this case?

I couldn't find anything related to this issue in google.
If I place winerror.h in curl folder, it complains about not finding windows.h and so on and so on

**Solved**

by using x86 version of Command Prompt

Comment: How did you invoke the VS Developer Command Prompt? You will probably want the x86 version.